# Gravity's self-energy

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime, self-energy

Suppose we have a single massive point particle.

In the absence of "potentials", the content of the stress-energy tensor would be dictated uniquely by the particle's mass and trajectory (possibly by means of Dirac deltas at the particle's position), meaning that the metric depends on the particle's trajectory (through EFE).

However, the absence of "potentials" imply this is a free particle, which means its trajectory depends on the metric (through the geodesics equation).

Thus, the solution to this problem would require to solve a set of nonlinear PDEs for the metric field (or for the particle's trajectory, I think it's equivalent, but I'm not sure).

How come? Does it mean the particle interacts with itself? If yes, what implications would this classical setting have to its QFT counterpart (subtraction schemes to account for self-energy, regularization etc.)?

Edit: by "potentials" I mean other matter or radiation fields interfering with the metric. I want my (single matter/radiation) source to be the single massive point particle.

Comment: By the Einstein equations from GR, if the space-time is curved and thus the Einstein tensor nonzero, the energy momentum tensor will be nonzero as well, so the assumption of a non-trivial metric and an empty universe is inconsistent. Unless you have in mind the curvature induced by the particle's mass itself?

Comment: This is precisely what I meant when I said that given the stress-energy tensor dependent on the trajectory, the metric (curvature) can be obtained (EFE: Einstein Field Equations).

Comment: To get started, you might try ["Introduction to Gravitational Self Force" by Bob Wald](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0412) or [Eric Poisson's Living Review article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2004-6).

Comment: I see! Well, as far as I know, the action is indeed non-linear in the metric field, already because of the $\sqrt{-g}$ factor in the integration measure, so there will be self interaction.

Comment: Here's a more recent review article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10385